# Flutter Creating multiple PDF Pages

Tags: flutter, pdf, multipage

I am trying to show results of a sql query as PDF page in flutter application. As long as the data do not cross a pagefull, it displays correctly. When data is more than a pagefull it results in "Exception: This widget created more than 20 pages. This may be an issue in the widget or the document. See [https://pub.dev/documentation/pdf/latest/widgets/MultiPage-class.html"](https://pub.dev/documentation/pdf/latest/widgets/MultiPage-class.html%22)

My pdf generating code is like below where 'data' is a list of map data.

```
    pdf.addPage(pw.MultiPage(
        pageFormat: PdfPageFormat.a4,
        build: (pw.Context context) {
          return <pw.Widget>[
            pw.Column(children: [
              pw.Table(children: [
                pw.TableRow(children: [
                  ...data[0].keys.map((e) => pw.Text(e)),
                ]),
                ...data.map((e) {
                  return pw.TableRow(children: [
                    ...e.values.map((v) => pw.Text(v)),
                  ]);
                }),
              ])
            ])
          ];
        }));
    return pdf.save();
  }
```

I tried wrapping the pw.Column in various combinations (Flex, Partition, Table, Wrap, GridView, and Column.) as listed in https://pub.dev/documentation/pdf/latest/widgets/MultiPage-class.html

I am not able to grasp how to span the data over multiple pages automatically using the Flex, Partition, Table, Wrap, GridView, and Column. How Do I do that ?

Or is there a way to detect current TableRow/Widget position and create new page on exceeding the page length (of course - margins)? Thanks a lot.

Comment: From the docs, I think that you have to wrap each of your children in a wrap widget inside of the build method. For ex: If you have one page then find the amount of data that can fit in the page and then wrap it with wrap widget and for next page wrap using wrap widget again.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved it by removing pw.Column  in the above code. It works perfectly now. i.e

```
return <pw.Widget>[
  pw.Table(children: [
  // rest of the code follows
```

Thanks